# Word meaning "likely to cause controversy?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The name Self-Arming Group isn't as [...] as Gun Club, but
>   controversial nevertheless.

What word can I use in the example above?

Comment: *Inflammatory* might work here.

Comment: I'm inclined to think in the opposite direction.  In my book, Self-Arming Group isn't as *neutral* as Gun Club, but controversial nonetheless.

Comment: Also consider phrases that contain terms like *[in your face](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-your-face)*, *[confrontational](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confrontational)*, *[out there](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_there#Adjective)*, *[edgy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edgy#Adjective)*, *[blatant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blatant#Adjective)*.

Comment: How about incendiary? I also think contentious sounds good.

Comment: Have you looked at a [thesaurus](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/k90JDaSgx8g5JPuuAmlhMstv/full.jpg)?

Comment: Your example sentence confuses me. I do not know what you intend it to mean, but to me "self-arming group" sounds like people organizing and stockpiling weapons in preparation for an insurgency. In contrast "gun club" sounds like people who shoot birds. Are you sure you want to say that the first is <b>less likely</b> to incite controversy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Polarizing* - In the world of politics, polarization (or polarisation) can refer to the divergence of political attitudes to ideological extremes.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(politics)

Comment: Except that, by any measure, "Self-Arming Group" is more polarizing and more inflammatory than "Gun Club".

Answer (score 6):

*Controversial*.  The adjective you want is *controversial*. Your sentence then would simply be saying that the one is more controversial than the other.  But anyway that's what *controversial* means: *likely to cause controversy* or *causing controversy*.

But if you are just looking for a synonym for *controversial*, then ask for that (but you could look it up).

- arguable
- contentious
- debatable
- disputable

Comment: Using *controversial* for the blank in the sentence might be stylistically interesting, though, because it appears again a few words later.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word *objectionable* could work in your sentence. The online *Oxford English Dictionary* [defines it as:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/objectionable)

> Arousing distaste or opposition; unpleasant or offensive.

So your sentence would be: *The name Self-Arming Group is not as objectionable as Gun Club, but controversial nonetheless.*

Comment: +1 for the word.  Even though I think that nobody in a Gun Club would care enough about being PC to actually refer themselves as a Self-Arming Group- They're a Gun Club.

Comment: Reference, please.

Answer (score 3):

contentious -

: likely to cause people to argue or disagree

: involving a lot of arguing

: likely or willing to argue

Source http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contentious

Answer (score 2):

> **inflamatory** *adj.* tending to excite anger, disorder, or tumult

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflammatory

> The name Self-Arming Group isn't as *inflamatory* as Gun Club, but is controversial nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Speech which stirs up strong feelings on a controversial issue is [**provocative**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/provocative):

> Causing anger or another strong reaction, especially deliberately

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: A dictionary definition and link would strengthen this answer.

Comment: Hello, David. Your answer was flagged as low-quality by the system for its length and content. Please try to include a dictionary definition, link and source when you post an answer. It will never be flagged then. I edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

These don't mean *likely to cause controversy*, but they seem to work in your example sentence: *loaded* or *charged*. Perhaps *emotionally charged*.

**Edit**: I just realized, *loaded* is awesome in your example sentence.